# SSL/TLS issue on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2008-r2, schannel

I am trying to make a web service call with a client certificate
I get an error could not establish secure SSL/TLS channel
I have checked the client certificate credentials, permissions. All are fine.

In the log for schannel I see this

1. first schannel log is

﻿﻿﻿CSP Name: Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider

CSP Type: 1
   Key Name: xxxxx
   **Key Type: unknown** 
   Key Flags: 0x20

2. second schannel log is this fatal error

**schannel fatal alert ﻿﻿﻿80. The internal error state is 301.**

3. Third schannel log is

﻿An SSL Client handshake completed successfully. the negotiated cryptographic parameters are as follows
 Protocol: TLS 1.0
 Ciphersuite: 0x2f
 Exchange Strength: 2048

So this fatal error is breaking my logic.  I don't understand why its being thrown when the SSL handshake is then completed successfully.

Please help!!!!

Thanks

Comment: also this Key Type: unknown looks very suspect

Comment: We ran an SSLDiag utility and believe there may be an issue with the "Key Container" and the "Unique container name" for the imported client certificate The "Unique container name" is missing altogether. The "Key Container" has this single {GUID} whereas it should be something like {uniqueguid}_{machineguid}. This is really odd and we are not sure where or how to fix this for the certificate. Any help or pointers are appreciated. Thanks